# Spring Boot Actuator: Caching /actuator/health/readiness and /actuator/health/custom health check results

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cache

So I have added the Spring Boot Actuator to my application and I specified in the `application.properties` property `management.endpoint.health.cache.time-to-live=120s` to cache health check results. So when I call `/actuator/health`, the result is cached and it's good.

The problem starts when I call `/actuator/health/readiness` or custom created group `/actuator/health/deep` this request results are not cached. I went through [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.caching) and found only information for the main health endpoint, nothing for specific groups.

So my question is: did I miss sth? Or how can I implement caching for specific spring boot actuator endpoints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So I didn't find out of a box solution, so decided to go with the AOP approach.

I found `HealthEndpointWebExtension` class that manages health rest endpoints.
This class has two health methods, one one of them called for common `/health` endpoint and second when we call `health/<group name>`.

So I created Aspect around the second method, which allowed me to add cache for endpoints I need.

```java
@Around("execution(@org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.ReadOperation * org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(..,java.lang.String...))) && args(.., path)")
public Object cache(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String... path) throws Throwable {
    // Logic to get cache per endpoint and process if cache specifed.
}
```

At the end `application.properties` looks like this:

```
// out of the box
management.endpoint.health.cache.time-to-live=120s 

// customly created properties
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.cache.time-to-live=60s
management.endpoint.health.group.deep.cache.time-to-live=120s
```